# Difference between "in" and "to" in this context

Tags: differences, prepositions, nuance

My friend is taking an English conversation class. In it, she said

> I have been teaching math in high schools for more than 10 years. Before that I taught math **in** junior high schools.

However, her teacher corrected her, telling her she should change **in** junior high to **to** junior high schools.

Is there any reasons that we should use **to**? Isn't **in** correct?

Comment: The teacher is wrong. One teaches *to* students but *in* or *at* an institution.

Comment: I think you should get a grammar book. This is off topic. So basic.

Answer (score 2):

As StoneyB states above, you teach *in* a building, *in/at* a school/institution. Just as you live *in* a house, eat *in/at* a restaurant, or sleep *in* a bedroom.

You cannot teach math to a place. You *can't* teach math **to** junior high schools, to houses, to restaurants, or to rooms. You can, however, teach math **to** junior high school *students*, *to* elementary school students, *to* high school students, *to* college students, or *to*  *anyone* who wants to learn.